# dotCover файл покрытия на несколько типов тестов

Tags: teamcity, nunit, mstest

Добрый день! Интересует такой вопрос : могу ли я написать xml'ку для dotCover для нескольких типов тестов?!

Все просто. Для каждого моего проекта рядом с солюшеном будет лежать dotCoverSignature.xml файлик который будет внутри себя держать описание MsTest тестов и nUnit тестов.

Кое какая информация есть тут : [Running Coverage Analysis from the Command Line](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html)

Сборка осуществляется на TeamCity. Хочу обойтись малой кровью - одним билдстепом и конфигурацией прямо рядом с солюшеном.

Comment: не очень понимаю зачем так делать. у вас разные билды в одном солюшне, и в каждом из них вы хотите запускать только нужные тесты?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor не правильно выразился - для каждого моего проекта на teamcity

Comment: не хотите использовать jetbrains dotcover?   и расскажите о вашем типе раннера для билда, дополнив вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorPomidor проблему я кстати решил. и использую я dotCover. просто делаю два xml файла (один для mstest другой для nunit). на каждый из них у меня по отдельному билдстепу. дальше SonarQube на последнем билдстепе забирает отчеты в формате html и результаты тестов ( trx формат - mstest, xml - nunit)

Comment: можете написать ваше решение в качестве ответа.  если я не ошибаюсь, то можно было ExcludeFilters  указать в одном xml файле для разные раннеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение пришло после более подробного прочтения документации по dotCover и по плагину SonarQube для teamcity.

Процесс билда такой :

1. запускаем раннер SonarQube указываем ему какие брать файлы
   репортов (html файлы с метриками покрытия) и какие файлы брать с
   результатами тестов (trx - mstest, xml - nUnit).
2. запускаем msbuild
3. запускаем dotCover analyse для msTest
4. запускаем dotCover analyse для nUnit
5. завершаем раннер SonarQube чтобы он пропарсил все и выгрузил

Суть такова. Этот процесс билда мы описываем как шаблон для всех наших проектов. Если проект содержит один из видов тестов мы кладем к солюшену необходимый нам xml файл с конфигами, если оба сразу - то следовательно два конфига.

Сигнатура конфигов такая :

Для msTest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
    <TargetExecutable>
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
    </TargetExecutable>
<TargetArguments> /testcontainer:test.dll /testcontainer:test2.dll /resultsfile:MSTestResults.trx</TargetArguments>
    <Filters>
        <IncludeFilters>
            <FilterEntry>
                <ModuleMask>testInterface</ModuleMask>
            </FilterEntry>
            <FilterEntry>
                <ModuleMask>testInterface2</ModuleMask>
            </FilterEntry>
        </IncludeFilters>
        <ExcludeFilters />
    </Filters>
    <TargetWorkingDir>.</TargetWorkingDir>
    <Output>report_mstest.html</Output>
    <ReportType>HTML</ReportType>
</AnalyseParams>
```

**ВАЖНОЕ ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ!** в `TestArguments` не должно находится символов перевода новой строки и табуляции, я не знаю почему так, но с ними не работает, лучше все в одну строчку.Таких проблем с nUnit конфигом нет

для nUnit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
    <TargetExecutable>
        C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe
    </TargetExecutable>
    <TargetArguments>
        Autotests.dll
    </TargetArguments>
    <Result>NUnitResults.xml</Result>
    <Filters>
        <IncludeFilters>
            <FilterEntry>
                <ModuleMask>testInterface</ModuleMask>
            </FilterEntry>
            <FilterEntry>
                <ModuleMask>testInterface2</ModuleMask>
            </FilterEntry>
        </IncludeFilters>
        <ExcludeFilters />
    </Filters>
    <TargetWorkingDir>.</TargetWorkingDir>
    <Output>report_nunit.html</Output>
    <ReportType>HTML</ReportType>
</AnalyseParams>
```